# How to extend a listview?

Tags: android, listview, customization

-I try to extend a ListView widget to override onKeyDown method like this:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        // My instructions
    }
}
```

-In my xml file:

```
<com.test.two.MyListView android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/lv"
```

-In my Activity:

```
MyListView lv = (MyListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

but it doesn't work, what is the right way to extends a listview widget, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to archive?

Comment: which one is not working onKeyDown or ListView ? Why you want to extend the ListView ? What is the actual requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

Your custom ListView should implement View.OnKeyListener:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView implements View.OnKeyListener
```

and you should register it as the onKey listener of your list view:

```
lv.setOnKeyListener(this)
```

It also should have focus to receive onKey events

```
lv.setFocusableInTouchMode(True);
lv.requestFocus();
```

and finally, if you need to receive key events other than keyDown, you should return true from the `onKey()` to prevent Android system from handling the key event.

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be that you apparently try to place your code below the return-statement of the method.
Depending on what you try to do you might want to place your code above or return the value of the super call later.